# Nil is not compatible with expected argument type Optional<UnsafeMutableRawPointer>

Tags: swift3

I'm just updating my iOS app's code to Swift 3 and this line is foxing me:

```swift
let dataProvider:CGDataProvider? = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(nil, maskImagePixelData!, maskImagePixelData!.count, nil)
```

That worked in the previous version of Swift I was using, now it throws this error:

> Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'CGDataProviderReleaseDataCallback' (aka '@convention(c) (Optional<UnsafeMutableRawPointer>, UnsafeRawPointer, Int) -> {}')

I cannot find the documentation for `CGDataProviderCreateWithData` (!) but the signature is also confusing me:

```
CG_EXTERN CGDataProviderRef __nullable CGDataProviderCreateWithData(
    void * __nullable info, const void * cg_nullable data, size_t size,
    CGDataProviderReleaseDataCallback cg_nullable releaseData)
```

Is there a simple replacement for `nil` or do I need to move into some kind of `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it:

```swift
    let releaseMaskImagePixelData: CGDataProviderReleaseDataCallback = { (info: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, data: UnsafeRawPointer, size: Int) -> () in
        // https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgdataproviderreleasedatacallback
        // N.B. 'CGDataProviderRelease' is unavailable: Core Foundation objects are automatically memory managed
        return
    }
    var dataProvider:CGDataProvider? = CGDataProvider(dataInfo: nil, data: maskImagePixelData!, size: maskImagePixelData!.count, releaseData: releaseMaskImagePixelData)
```

And with `CGDataProvider.init` replacing `CGDataProviderCreateWithData` the documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgdataprovider)